# After a meditator or yogi enters into samadhi state what should he concentrate at?

Tags: yoga, meditation, samadhi

After a yogi enters into the samadhi state by doing concentration on some object, I've heard and read that he enters into such a state where all the physical sensations, sound, and sight goes. And his mind becomes totally silent. [reference](http://oceanoffruition.blogspot.in/2013/06/essence-of-shrimad-bhagwat-english.html) After this I don't understand logically how should he again progress his concentration, or on what object he should concentrate since all his sensations have gone.
I am only trying to understand how meditation works logically. I am a little confused with this part.

Comment: Dear @DineshLama, your name suggests that you belong to a buddhist tradition of monks. Is your teacher unavailable for answers. For they are the best source of information on such aspects especially if they have initiated you in the first place.

Comment: That's fine. Looking for a path that suits us is fine. But trying to learn without a teacher is hazardous to say the least. Please look for a proper teacher.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda says "Control the mind, cut off the senses, the you are a Yogi; after that all the rest will come." Worry about how to scale the mountain in front of you, do not worry about what is on the other side of the mountain. If you can cut off your senses then your own mind will show you what to concentrate on after that. Take care of today and tomorrow will take care of itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In samadhi, there is a state of non-duality. When there is "something" to focus on then it is a state of duality. So in the state of samadhi, the object of mediation and meditator are one and the same. Hence there is nothing to focus upon. There is only awareness and bliss.

> ता एव सबीजस्समाधिः ॥४६॥ (patanjali yoga sutra)
>
> tā eva sabījas-samādhiḥ ॥46॥
>
> All of these states of consciousness are called sabija samadhi. ||46||
>
> tasyāpi nirodhe sarva-nirodhān-nirbījaḥ samādhiḥ ॥51॥ (PY)
>
> Nirbiija samadhi is attained once even these impressions have become
> tranquil and when everything has become tranquil. ||51||

From the book of Yogananda Paramahansa

> Patanjali defines these states in his classification of the various
> stages of interiorized meditation. In Yoga Sutras 1:17-18, he refers
> to two basic categories of samadhi:
>
> (1) samprajnata and
>
> (2) asamprajnata.
>
> As applied to advanced stages of realization, samprajnata refers to
> savikalpa ("with difference") samadhi, or divine union in which there
> remains some distinction between the knower and the known, as in the
> realization "Thou and I are One." In greater or lesser degree, some
> modifications of nature remain. But in asamprajnuta samadhi, all
> differentiations of nature are resolved into the one Spirit. The
> consciousness of "Thou and I are One" becomes "I am He, who has become
> this little form of 'I' and all forms." This is not the egotist's
> proclamation, "I am God!"—the brass crown of megalomania—but rather
> the full realization of the absolute truth: God is the only Reality.
> Thus asamprajnata, in its absolute definition, is nirvikalpa ("without
> difference") samadhi, the highest yoga or union manifested by fully
> liberated masters or those on the threshold of soul freedom. (...)
>
> Patanjali divides samprajnata samadhi into four stages:
>
> (1) savitarka ("with doubt or conjecture"): intuitive experience mixed
> with argumentative or doubt-ridden mind;
>
> (2) savichara ("with reasoning or pondering"): intuitive experience
> mixed with discrimination-guided intellect;
>
> (3) sananda ("with joy"): interiorized intuitive experience
> interpreted by chitta or joy-permeated feeling; and
>
> (4) sasmita ("with 'I-ness'" or individuality): intuitive experience
> mixed with a pure sense of being.
>
> These four states, which come after interiorization (pratyahara), are
> the result of deep concentration (dharana), or superconscious
> perception as limited to the body. (Yoga Sutras 1:17)
>
> When these four stages of samprajnata have been resolved one by one
> into the next higher state, the yogi goes beyond them and attains
> asamprajnata samadhi. This comes in deep meditation (dhyana) in which
> concentration (dharana) is continuous, with no flicker of
> interruption; then the object of meditation (i.e., a particular
> concept or manifestation of God) is experienced as manifested not only
> in the body but in omnipresence. Beyond these states, in the advanced
> stages of realization, samprajnata and asamprajnata are understood to
> mean, respectively, savikalpa and nirvikalpa samadhi. Patanjali says
> that attainment of the highest samadhi is possible "by profound,
> devoted meditation on (the Lord) Ishvara (1:23).... His symbol is Aum
> (1:27)." (Chapter I, God Talks With Arjuna: The Bhagavad Gita by
> Paramahansa Yogananda)

Comment: **Hence there is nothing to focus upon**. But on smadhi one must use a mantra of his/her beloved Lord. Hence he must have full focus on his Lord. By this way many has chants mantra of their lord (Aaradhya) and got boom from them. Isn't that true that their complete focus was on their Lord, that's why Lord grant them boon? If they are chanting Shiva mantra then Shiva will get Happy coz focus was on Shiva. If there is nothing to focus then which Lord will be happy by us and why?

Comment: @Rishabh that is contemplation.  which is called Dharana or dhyana. After this in samadhi you and god are not separate. so nothing to contemplate upon. You are one with the source. Samadhi is elated state of being. Its not for making any gods happy. Mantra or other mediums are until the stage of dharana.

Comment: Someone becomes able to chat with Lord directly (heard a lot about this and saw live examples also). They can talk with lord whenever they want. Is this can be possible when someone once reached at Samadhi state? Or this can be done without samadhi also? What you think about this?

Comment: @Rishabh Communication with the Lord is not a verbal one. In samadhi there is only one so with whom to talk ?

Answer (score 1):

In Samadhi the mind rests on Supreme Brahma. It no longer operates in the physical or mental plane. The object of meditation has been achieved.

**Samadhi**

> Said the God of Fire: **Samadhi denotes a state of mind in which the
> consciousness, appearing in its spiritual aspect, remains calm and
> self-contained in itself like a pacified lake or sea and ceases to be
> operative in the physical and intellectual plains. A yogin, whose mind
> deeply absorbed in meditation, remains steady and un-flickering like
> the flame of a lamp kept in a windless chamber or receptacle, is said
> to have attained to the spiritual state of Samadhi. In this experience
> a yogin usually loses all his faculties of sense-perception. He hears
> not, sees not, smells not, feels not when not touched, thinks not, but
> is inert and inoperative as a log of wood and spiritually rests in the
> bosom of Supreme Brahma, steady and stationary like the un-flickering
> lamp light in a windless room.**
>
> Miraculous powers and celestial
> attributes spontaneously develop themselves in a yogin, absorbed in
> meditating upon the universal soul symbolized by the god Vishnu and
> thus unmistakably indicate his success in connection with his practice
> of yoga. The gods wait upon him with the offerings of articles which
> they themselves enjoy in heaven. The yogin sees, with unaided eyes,
> unbounded treasures lying concealed in the bowels of the earth and
> hears the music of celestial spheres swelling in eddies around his
> person. Kings and rich men seek his favours by the gift of enormous
> wealth. The Vedas, the books of scriptures and sciences, as well as
> poetry and celestial alchemy, reveal to him their respective secrets
> and voluntarily furnish him with all knowledge contained in them. He
> becomes a healer of malady and a skillful artisan without going
> through the necessary term of training. Beautiful virgins of paradise
> hail him with their overtures and unsolicited affections. But a true
> yogin discards all these as so many trifles and with such man alone
> the god Visnu is pleased.

**Agni Purana 376.1-10**